# Can I deactivate the Windows 11 Pro account requirement after installation?

Tags: windows-11, windows-installation

During setup you can skip this requirement. Can I disable this afterwards? I'm using Windows Pro.

Comment: Windows 11 Home?  No.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm using Pro, have added that to the question.

Comment: With Pro you can use a Local Account. You can change your Microsoft Account to a Local Account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now that the situation has been clarified, yes, with Windows 10 or 11 Pro you can change from a Microsoft Account to a Local Account and to your specific question, you can do this after Windows has been installed.

Good Resource:

[Change to local account](https://www.xda-developers.com/windows-11-microsoft-local-account/#:%7E:text=Switching%20to%20a%20local%20account,-Even%20if%20you&text=To%20do%20this%2C%20open%20the,set%20up%20your%20local%20account.)

> Switching to a local account Even if you set up your computer with a
> Microsoft account initially, you can still switch to a local account
> whenever you want. You're not actually forced to use your Microsoft
> account for as long as you have your PC. To do this, open the Settings
> app, then go to the Accounts section. Click Your info, then choose
> Sign in with a local account instead.
>
> Confirm that you want to sign out of your Microsoft account, and
> verify your identity. Then you'll need to set up your local account. A
> password is optional, but naturally, we'd recommend using one.
>
> After that, click Sign out and finish, and you'll be logged out of
> your current account. Then you can sign into your local account from
> the lock screen. Keep in mind your Microsoft account may still be used
> in some apps, including the Microsoft Store. You can sign out of these
> individually, too.

Answer (score 2):

To install Windows 11 with a local account and without a
Microsoft account :

- Install Windows 11 normally with internet connection untill you
  reach the Microsoft sign-in screen
- Enter exactly `a@a.com` under the email field and click on Next
- On the next screen, enter any password and click on Sign in
- When the screen comes up for "Oops, something went wrong", click Next
- Windows 11 will now let you create a local account on Windows 11.

For more information with screenshots, see the article
[How to Create a Local Account on Windows 11 (Home and Pro Editions)](https://beebom.com/how-create-local-account-windows-11/).